# Finding KL Divergence from set of numbers

Tags: python, statistics, data-science, probability-distribution

If I have 2 lists of numbers (shown below), how could I find the KL Divergence? Do I first have to find the probability distribution in them (if so, how could one do that)?

I've tried putting the data through a kernel density function but it has not worked

```py
data = [18, 16, 46, 4, 10, 7, 14, 51, 7, 4, 49, 9, 7, 7]
data = np.reshape(data, (-1, 1)) # Reshape data for KernelDensity() function
data2 = [0, 17, 0, 20, 77, 23, 7, 8, 8, 19, 0, 48, 19, 7, 4, 7, 16]
data2 = np.reshape(data2, (-1, 1)) # Reshape data for KernelDensity() function

from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity
kd = KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian', bandwidth=0.75).fit(data)
kd2 = KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian', bandwidth=0.75).fit(data2)

from scipy.special import kl_div
kl_div(kd, kd2)
```

When I run the code, I receive the following error

> TypeError: ufunc 'kl_div' not supported for the input types, and the
> inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to
> the casting rule ''safe''

I've been trying to figure this out for a few hours. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try rel_entr? `from scipy.special import rel_entr` `sum(rel_entr(kd, kd2))` should return the kL of the two distributions kd and kd2.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. When I try rel_entr, I get the same error message:

`TypeError: ufunc 'rel_entr' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`

Comment: Yes. your data should be same as list. Your input data is a real data? or the distribution of the data?

Comment: @Sadcow my data is the actual data not the distribution of the data. How can I turn it into a distribution?